# Responsive CSS only working in mobile view, refusing to hide in normal view

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, haml

I've created two different footers for a page, given them two different ID's, and then written CSS so that one footer is hidden and the other shown for regular browsing, and then the opposite for mobile browsing. You know the drill.

```
@media (max-width: $screen-lg) {
  #main-footer {
    display: block;
  }

  #mobile-footer {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: $phone_width) {
  #main-footer {
    display: none;
  }

  #mobile-footer {
    display: block;

    // I believe all the CSS below is irrelevant, but posted for completeness 
    max-width: 550px;
    .content {
      max-width: 550px;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      width: inherit;
    }
    .content .left {
      max-width: 550px;
      float: none;
      text-align: center;
      ul {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        li img {
          margin-left: 5px;
        }
      }
    }
    .content .right {
      max-width: 550px;
      float: none;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .content .right .links {
      text-align: center;
      ul {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        li {
        margin-left: 5px;
        }
      }
    }
    .content .right .copyright {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  }
}
```

And here's what the HAML looks like:

```
- hide_groove ||= false
- hide_inquiry ||= false
- skip_javascript ||= false

%footer{class: ("signed_in" if user_signed_in?), id: "main-footer"}

  - unless user_signed_in?
    %div{style: 'display: none'}
      = render 'shared/stuff_sign_up_form'

  .content

    .row.sign_up_and_location

      .left
        = render 'shared/like_on_facebook', size: '', dimension: 38, float: 'left', spacing: '5px'

      .right

        .links{style: 'clear: right;'}
          %ul
            %li= link_to 'About', main_app.about_path
            %li= link_to 'Submit a Stuff', main_app.submit_a_stuff_path
            %li= link_to 'Advertise', main_app.advertise_path
            %li= link_to 'Jobs', main_app.jobs_path
            %li= link_to 'FAQ', main_app.faq_path
            %li= link_to 'Contact', main_app.contact_path
            %li= link_to 'Terms', main_app.terms_path
            %li= link_to 'Privacy', main_app.privacy_path
          .copyright 
            (copyright stuff)

  = render 'shared/stuff_submission_prompt' if @show_stuff_submission_prompt
  = render 'shared/stuff_submission_prompt' if @show_stuff_submission_prompt


%footer{id: "mobile-footer"}
  .content

    .left
      %ul
        %li
          = link_to 'https://www.facebook.com/StuffHQ', target: "_blank" do
            = image_tag asset_path("social/social-media-icons-facebook-v1.png")
        %li
          = link_to 'http://www.pinterest.com/stuff', target: "_blank" do
            = image_tag asset_path("social/social-media-icons-pinterest-v1.png")
        %li
          = link_to 'https://twitter.com/stuff', target: "_blank" do
            = image_tag asset_path("social/social-media-icons-twitter-v1.png")
        %li
          = link_to 'https://plus.google.com/+Stuff', target: "_blank" do
            = image_tag asset_path("social/social-media-icons-google-plus-v1.png")
        %li
          = link_to 'http://instagram.com/stuff', target: "_blank" do
            = image_tag asset_path("social/social-media-icons-instagram-v1.png")

    .right
      .links
        %ul
          %li= link_to 'About', main_app.about_path
          %li= link_to 'Contact', main_app.contact_path
          %li= link_to 'Advertise', main_app.advertise_path
          %li= link_to 'Jobs', main_app.jobs_path
          %li= link_to 'FAQ', main_app.faq_path
          %li= link_to 'Terms', main_app.terms_path
          %li= link_to 'Privacy', main_app.privacy_path
      .copyright
       (copyright stuff)
```

In mobile view everything works great: only the #mobile-footer appears and #main-footer is not displayed. However, in normal view, both footers display on top of one another, though as far as I can tell, display: none; should be taking care of that. What am I missing here?

UPDATE: I have no idea why, but for some reason changing @media (max-width: $screen-lg) (which is 1200px btw) to:

```
@media (max-width: 2000px)
```

Fixed the issue, but I have no idea why...and I'm concerned about why I would need a hack like that. So new question: anyone know why changing the max-width works?

Comment: Are you sure your $screen-lg variable is set correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing both of the footers is because you're viewing your website at a greater size than your `$screen-lg` variable.

If you take a look at this fiddle, you'll see that when you make the browser window less than the `$screen-lg` variable (in this case, 1000px), you'll see the desktop footer only. When you get smaller than the `$phone_width` variable, you'll only see the mobile footer.
http://jsfiddle.net/2ckj8zzr/

What you need to do is replace your desktop `max-width` media query with a `min-width: $phone_width`. This will display the desktop footer on any screen size greater than the `$phone_width` variable.

Change:

```
@media (max-width: $screen-lg) {
  #main-footer {
    display: block;
  }

  #mobile-footer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

to:

```
@media (min-width: $phone_width) {
  #main-footer {
    display: block;
  }

  #mobile-footer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ckj8zzr/1/

Comment: It ended up being slightly more complicated than I anticipated (I had to deal with making sure we displayed *no* footer in tablet widths), but you definitely got me on the right track with using min-width. Thank you for the thorough response!

Comment: You're welcome!
For the tablet, I would recommend using a range media query to display the footer as none.
`@media (min-width: $phone_width) and (max-width: $screen-lg)`